# Filtering row's' values and assigning a binary variable

Tags: python, pandas

I would appreciate some help on understanding how to assign a label 1 to rows which satisfy the following conditions:

- if `Word` column contains `Amber` or `Light` or `Yellow` then `1`;
- else `0`

I have tried as follows

```
df[(df.Word=='Amber') & (df.Word=='Light') & (df.Word=='Yellow') ]['IND'] = 1 but it does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one problem is chain slice assign
To fix your code

```
df['IND'] = 0
df.loc[df['Word'].isin(['Amber','Light', 'Yellow']),'IND'] = 1
```

However we usually do

```
df['IND'] = np.where(df['Word'].isin(['Amber','Light', 'Yellow']), 1 ,0 )
```

Or

```
df['IND'] = df['Word'].isin(['Amber','Light', 'Yellow']).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you BEN_YO. I have found very good and useful your answer.